# GORM unable to query all records using .Find()

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to write a function to query all results that match a set of conditions and save them in a struct slice.

```
// Queries the database for the given set of fields and some string conditions specified as a map
func QueryAllRecords(db *gorm.DB, outputObject interface{}, conditions map[string]interface{}) {

    result := db.Where(conditions).Find(&outputObject)
    if result.Error != nil {
        panic(result.Error)
    }
    log.Println(Utils.CreateLogMessage("Queried all records", outputObject))
}
```

According to the GORM docs (https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Retrieving-all-objects), I can query all records using the `.Find()` function and then specify the struct where the output of the query will be saved.

This is where I make my function call to `QueryAllRecords`:

```
var outputObject []Models.Product
conditions := map[string]interface{}{"name": "Sample Product"}

DB.QueryAllRecords(db, outputObject, conditions)
fmt.Println(outputObject)
```

When I try to print `outputObject`, I get an empty an empty slice `[]`. It seems like the `.Find(&outputObject)` is not saving the result in the slice like I want it to. I can successfully print `outputObject` within the function itself, but not after it has returned.

Comment: Can you provide a runnable program + version in go playground (https://go.dev/play/)

Comment: How do I set up a temporary database with relevant tables in go playground?

Comment: @nikhil0929 you can use sqlite in-memory version to create example app for reference you can check [here](https://gorm.io/docs/connecting_to_the_database.html#SQLite) under note section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DB.QueryAllRecords(db, outputObject, conditions)` instead